# Request locale different: Controller argument vs RequestStack

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, event-listener

I'm trying to figure out why my locale is different in one of my controllers and when I get the request from the request stack.

Here's an example of one of my routes: 'website.com/nl'

```
/**
 * Main page of the website
 * @Route("/{_locale}",
 *     name="home",
 *     defaults={"_locale": "nl"},
 *     requirements={
 *         "_locale": "nl|en|fr"
 *     },
 * )
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $_locale
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function home(
    Request $request,
    $_locale
) {
    // $_locale === "nl"
    // $request->getLocale() === "nl"
}
```

As expected based on the url, the locale is NL

Now when I need the locale in one of my services or event listeners, I need to use `RequestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getLocale()`. However, this locale is always set to locale: "en"

Service mapping:

```
app.doctrine.locale_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\LocaleListener
    public: false
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    lazy: true
    tags:
      - { name: "doctrine.orm.entity_listener", entity: App\Entity\Translation\Translatable, event: postLoad }
```

Entity listener:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Translation\Translatable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class LocaleListener
{
    private $currentLocale;
    public function __construct(RequestStack $rs)
    {
        $this->currentLocale = $rs->getCurrentRequest()->getLocale();
        // $this->currentLocale === "en"
    }

    public function postLoad(Translatable $translatable, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $translatable->setLocale($this->currentLocale);
        // e.g. url: mywebsite.be/nl
        // Why is $this->currentLocale === "en"?
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly because the listener is being instantiated before the request itself is processed.  Just store the request stack in the constructor then do the getCurrentRequest stuff in the postLoad method and see if that helps.

Comment: Hey @Cerad, You're absolutely right, it works! I may have ignored [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html) about creating a custom listener to change the locale before initialisation of my own listeners :/
You may want to post this as your answer so I can accept it